# Why does nchar variable work when the columns referenced are char?

Tags: sql, t-sql, variables, char, varchar

This is a question based on curiosity. I was trying to solve the following problem:

1. My stored proc produces results within 1-2 seconds of running, no problems.
2. When I run my proc through SSRS, the page gets stuck on loading and never produces results. Takes about 30 seconds - one minute to become unstuck and quit processing the query.
3. Any table I am referencing/joining on my variable has the SAME data type, char(3).

Below is the code:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Inventory_pr_rpt_Scanfile_InvalidColorSize]

(
    @STORE CHAR(3)
)
AS


--set statistics io on 


/** TEST **/

    --DECLARE   @STORE CHAR(3)
    --SET       @STORE = '180'


/** Drop existing temp table **/ 

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP_ScanBadData') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP_ScanBadData

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP_ScanDiscrepancy') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP_ScanDiscrepancy

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP_ScanFinalReport') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP_ScanFinalReport    


    CREATE TABLE #TEMP_ScanBadData (scan_store char(3)
                                      ,scan_sku char(45)
                                      ,scan_qty int
                                      ,errormessage varchar(255))

    CREATE TABLE #TEMP_ScanFinalReport(scan_store char(3)
                                      ,scan_sku char(45)
                                      ,scan_qty int
                                      ,storeOH_qty int
                                      ,errormessage varchar(255))   

    CREATE TABLE #TEMP_ScanDiscrepancy(scan_store char(3)
                                      ,scan_sku char(45)
                                      ,scan_qty int
                                      ,storeOH_qty int
                                      ,errormessage varchar(255))                             

/** Does SKU exist in our system? (Valid color/size/style check) **/
INSERT INTO #TEMP_ScanBadData (scan_store
                                      ,scan_sku
                                      ,scan_qty
                                      ,errormessage)
    SELECT scan_store
        ,scan_sku
        ,scan_qty
        ,'SKU does not exist.' as errormessage           
    FROM [LP].[dbo].[scan_file]
    WHERE scan_sku NOT IN (SELECT ItemID
                           FROM [Product].[dbo].[MasterSKU])
    AND scan_store = @STORE



/** Does scanned SKU exist in store on hand? **/
    INSERT INTO #TEMP_ScanDiscrepancy (scan_store
                                      ,scan_sku
                                      ,scan_qty
                                      ,storeOH_qty
                                      ,errormessage)    
    SELECT aa.scan_store 
          ,aa.scan_sku
          ,aa.scan_qty
          ,'' as storeOH_qty
          ,'Scanned SKU missing in store OH.' as errormessage
    FROM [LP].[dbo].[scan_file] aa
    FULL OUTER JOIN [Product].[dbo].[CurrentOnHand] bb
            ON aa.scan_sku = bb.ItemID
            and aa.scan_store = bb.Store 
    WHERE bb.ItemID IS NULL
    AND aa.scan_store = @STORE
    and bb.Store = @STORE


/** Were any store OH SKU's missed in scan? **/
    INSERT INTO #TEMP_ScanDiscrepancy (scan_store
                                      ,scan_sku
                                      ,scan_qty
                                      ,storeOH_qty
                                      ,errormessage)    
    SELECT aa.Store   as 'scan_store'
          ,aa.ItemId  as 'scan_sku'
          ,aa.OnHandU as 'scan_qty'
          ,'' as storeOH_qty
          ,'SKU was not scanned.' as errormessage
    FROM [Product].[dbo].[CurrentOnHand] aa
    LEFT JOIN [LP].[dbo].[scan_file] bb
            ON aa.ItemID = bb.scan_sku
            and aa.Store = bb.scan_store 
    WHERE bb.scan_sku IS NULL
    AND aa.Store = @STORE
    and bb.scan_store = @STORE

/** What are the qty differences between scanned and OH? **/
    INSERT INTO #TEMP_ScanDiscrepancy (scan_store
                                      ,scan_sku
                                      ,scan_qty
                                      ,storeOH_qty
                                      ,errormessage)    
    SELECT aa.scan_store
        ,aa.scan_sku
        ,aa.scan_qty
        ,bb.OnHandU as 'storeOH_qty'
        ,'QTY does not match between scan and store OH.' as errormessage
    FROM [LP].[dbo].[scan_file] aa
    JOIN [Product].[dbo].[CurrentOnHand] bb
        ON bb.ItemId = aa.scan_sku
        AND aa.scan_store = bb.Store        
    WHERE bb.Store = @STORE
    AND bb.OnHandU <> aa.scan_qty   
    AND aa.scan_store = @STORE


      INSERT INTO #TEMP_ScanFinalReport (scan_store
      ,scan_sku
      ,scan_qty
      ,storeOH_qty
      ,errormessage)    
      SELECT scan_store 
          ,scan_sku 
          ,scan_qty 
          ,storeOH_qty 
          ,errormessage 
      FROM #TEMP_ScanDiscrepancy    

    INSERT INTO #TEMP_ScanFinalReport (scan_store
      ,scan_sku
      ,scan_qty
      ,storeOH_qty
      ,errormessage)    
      SELECT scan_store 
          ,scan_sku 
          ,scan_qty 
          ,'' as storeOH_qty 
          ,errormessage 
      FROM #TEMP_ScanBadData    

      SELECT *
      FROM #TEMP_ScanFinalReport
```

Resolution: After trying VARCHAR(3) and CHAR(3), I tried NCHAR(3), and that worked!

My question is: Why? If I viewed each table I am referencing and saw that the column for Store is always CHAR(3), and all the temp tables I created are CHAR(3), WHY does NCHAR(3) work?

I feel like it has something to do with how SSRS passes the text variable into the stored proc...but it still doesn't make sense to me how I can run the stored proc on the sql server with the variable set to CHAR, VARCHAR, and NCHAR. Why do all three work on the sql server, but only NCHAR works with the variable through SSRS?

**Table information:**

1. [LP].[dbo].[scan_file]

   - scan_store CHAR(3)
2. [Product].[dbo].[CurrentOnHand]

   - Store VARCHAR(4)

Comment: I'm not convinced that NCHAR was the solution, rather than being coincidental with some other change.   I would test by using profiler to look at the different queries that are passed in each case, and then look at the query plans for each of those queries.

Comment: I'm not convinced NCHAR is the real solution either, however I literally didn't make any other changes other than the data type for the variable. I will look into using profiler to see if that shines a light on something.

Comment: What is the type for the scan_store field in  the table  [LP].[dbo].[scan_file] aa   .  THis is what all other types should be.    Also   for testing use 3 character char variables like '333'  not '1'  or '12'    If you get a change in behavior then you will want to cast each comparison to the right type that is string padded.   In Other words '12 '   and '1  '  not '1' .  This is why I rarely use char and nchar.  It often gets you.    ALSO NChar is really2 bytes under the covers which causes other math problems when doing compares.

Comment: The type definition in SSRS is defined in the rs in a way that affects behavior of your problem probably.   I strongly recommend you make the parameter to the stored proc string and then force your sql code to cast and convert to NChar or Char so that external users always pass a string type.  String type is very well defined.

Comment: The type for scan_store from LP.dbo.scan_file is CHAR(3). All store numbers are 3 digits, so I have always been using 333, 123, et cetera.